# Are political donations to foreign politicians residing in Canada but campaigning abroad tax free?

Tags: taxes, international, canada, campaign-finance

There are a lot of new rules in Canada about political donations. But what about someone living in Canada who is campaigning to be elected abroad? Are donations taxable by the Federal government of Canada, or any other level of Canadian government? Are there any special provisions that need to be met by the politician receiving monies?

Comment: You mean beyond the provisions required by whichever country this person is running in?

Comment: Yes. I mean does Canada expect anything from them? If they get donations, campaign contributions to help them in their bid to be elected abroad, do they have to pay anything to Canada out of that amount? Do they have to claim or register anything or are they just scott free?

Comment: I bet that there are a lot of rules in Canada about political donations *to Canadian politics and politic parties*. But usually foreign campaigns/political parties are not registered (within Canada), I do not even know if that is possible. So I bet that it would most likely considered a "gift" rather than a "political donation".